# how would you transform this functional java code to scala above SparkContext?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, functional-java

Ok so I have `points` which is a `List<GeoPoint>`

The following piece of code is written using java 8 functional API. 
It takes the points, calculates for each point its matching cluster , and then groups them point by the `ClusterKey`. Eventually we end up with a `Map<ClusterKey, List<GeoPoint>` Here it is:

```
points.
   parallelStream().unordered().
   collect(groupingByConcurrent(Functions::calcClusterKey))
```

Comment: If you have another question, well, ask another question, don't change the existing one.

Answer (score 2):

```
sc.parallelize(points).groupBy(Functions.calcClusterKey).collect.toMap
```

The correspondence is pretty 1:1.

Comment: Pretty awesome man, and quick! thanks!. Only thing is that I read somewhere that groupBy may be problematic if my list contains a couple of million points, and that I should go for a solution which involves reduceByKey

Comment: `groupByKey` is indeed expensive, but if you want the full `Map` you're going to have to do something equivalent to it sooner or later. If you don't need the `Map` but are happy to do some sort of aggregation first then you should indeed keep it as an `RDD` and use `reduceByKey` (or better still, `aggregateByKey`) to perform further reductions first, something like `....map{v => (Functions.calcClusterKey(v), v)}.aggregateByKey(...)`.